# Wine: fixme :font: get_name_record_codepage encoding encoding 29 and 20 not handled, platform 1. Ubuntu 20.10

Tags: wine

Here's the problem every time a run `wine config` or install the anything on `winetricks`. The errors (below appear) yet everything runs and installs fine on `wine`. Also I just had to install font on 32Bit and 64Bit `winetricks` to resolve alot of font display issues.

```
fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 29 not handled, platform 1.

fixme:font:get_name_record_codepage encoding 20 not handled, platform 1.
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with my GNU/Linux Debian 10 and it happened after a MESA update. I suspect you are facing the same problem. You need to downgrade to a previous version of MESA. Apparently MESA 21 seems to have some issue with WINE. Good luck.

Comment: What's mesa, how  do I find out what version I have, let alone downgrade?